# How to get the direct link of URL by file_get_contents

Tags: php, browser

I have link like this,

```
https://www.example.com/enter_check/=/declared=yes/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fitem_detail
```

When you access by browser.

It jumps to `https://www.example.com/item_detail`

However I access with file_get_contents on PHP, it doesn't jump, Even,when I pretend the browser as User-Agent, still not work.

```
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/6.4 (compatible; MSIE 4.0; Windows 98; DigExt)',
        )));
    $source = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
```

Any ideas?? Is this possible to make `file_get_contents` work in the same way as the browser does?

Comment: It may be possible that redirection was performed using JS.

Comment: Does `curl -I` show a redirect or success? IE 4 and windows 98 might not come back as a supported browser.

Comment: @user3783243 `curl -I` shows `HTTP/1.1 302 Found`

Comment: Okay, so it is a server side redirect. The follow redirect should work for that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to add `follow_location` option to your context:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/6.4 (compatible; MSIE 4.0; Windows 98; DigExt)',
        'follow_location' => true,
)));
$source = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
```